# MySQL subquery error on the comparison variable in the subquery

Tags: mysql

I've tried several ways to implement a subquery in the select clause. Basically I just want to lookup a date in one table and store it in another table.  In this example I get an error "Unknown column 'areckey' in where clause"

```
insert into cmeFillCompaction  set
  reckey=2421,
  areckey=3170,
  WEBDATE=(select pickupdate from cmeSchedule s where s.reckey=areckey)
on duplicate key update
  reckey=2421,
  areckey=3170,
  WEBDATE=(select pickupdate from cmeSchedule s where s.reckey=areckey)
```

what would the proper syntax be?

Comment: `INSERT INTO YourTable (field1, field2) values (val1,val2)`

Comment: I prefer the alternate method of specifying the fields with the INSERT INTO yourTable SET col1=exp1, col2=exp2...  But that really was not my question.  It's the subquery which I have posted that I need help with. It works with a basic select but does not seem to work on the insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a correlated subquery like that, because the row doesn't yet exist to compare with. Use `INSERT...SELECT`. And you don't need to repeat the value in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause, you can use `VALUES(columnname)` to pick up the value that would have been assigned to that column if the `INSERT` had succeeded.

```
INSERT INTO cmeFillCompaction (reckey, areckey, webdate)
SELECT reckey, 3170, pickupdate
FROM cmeSchedule
WHERE reckey = 2421
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE webdate = VALUES(webdate)
```

Comment: Great.  I have a number of other fields/values to update as well.  I just list them in the same order?  Not quite sure on the syntax that's all

Comment: Just make sure that the fields in the `SELECT` match up with the list of columns in the `INSERT` line.

Comment: Ah! I see a problem after you guided me to the spot in the manual.  I only want to get the date field from the cmeSchedule table.  The remaining data does not come from that table.  Sounds like I need to do a lookup on the date as a separate a query

Comment: If it comes from some other table you can use a `JOIN`.

Comment: If they're literals, you can just put them in the `SELECT` list, like I did with `3170`.

Comment: The data comes from an JSON/ajax call submitted via web server.  I just needed to recover the original assignment date from my scheduling table.  I did not think I could use join in conjunction with the INSERT command?  Since my INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY... is in a prepared statement, I will simply do a lookup query once before I enter the loop and insert the retrieved date.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `JOIN` is part of the `SELECT` sub-query that you're using to get the values for the `INSERT`. Anything you can use in an ordinary `SELECT` query can be used there as well.